# UPDATING a table which is selected using SELECT query in SQL

Tags: sql, select, presto, amazon-athena

I want to use the `Update` keyword with `select` something like

```
UPDATE(select col1,col2,col3 from UNPIVOTED_TABLE)
SET col1=0
WHERE col1 IS NULL
SET col2=0
WHERE col2 is NULL
SET col3=0
WHERE col3 is NULL
```

I know my syntax is not right but this basically is what i am trying to achieve

I am selecting 3 columns and there are some `null` values which i want to update and set it as 0

Also i cannot update the table itself since the original table was `UNPIVOTED` and i am `PIVOTING` it in the select statement and i need the pivoted result (that is the columns i have selected) (col1,col2,col3)

Also i am using amazon Athena if that is relevant

Comment: Are you looking for an `update` statement (that actuallu modify data in some table), or for a `select`?

Comment: You would probably need to show us sample data and expected results to clarify your question. Your SQL does not make sense.

Comment: Are you using athena, or MySQL? These are two different database products, please only tag the one that you are using.

Comment: This is just `UPDATE UNPIVOTED_TABLE SET col1 = COALESCE(col1, 0), col2 = COALESCE(col2, 0), col3 = COALESCE(col3, 0) WHERE col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NUL or col3 IS NULL` ?

Comment: sorry for the tags.. i am using athena... i dont want to update the actual table just how it is displayed for ex i want to display 0 instead of null if that is possible :)

Comment: @alikhan it's presto syntax? Seems it has coalesce: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html

Comment: *i want to display 0 instead of null* If your visual component have no setting for to display zero instead of null then the only way is to use a query as its datasource instead of the table.

Comment: @CaiusJard I see its presto but i cannot update the table, can i use it without updating the table maybe with the select statement ?

Comment: @Akina Thats what i am trying to do but don't exactly know how

Comment: Use `SELECT id, ... , COALESCE(col1, 0) AS col1, COALESCE(col2, 0) AS col2, COALESCE(col2, 0) col3, ... FROM UNPIVOTED_TABLE;` query instead of table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you just want `coalesce()`:

```
select 
    coalesce(col1, 0) col1,
    coalesce(col2, 0) col2,
    coalesce(col3, 0) col3
from unpivoted_table
```

`colaesce()` checks if the first argument is `null`: if it doesn't, it returns the original value as-is, otherwise it returns the value given a second argument instead.

Comment: Thank you so much

so for varchar if i wanted to set all the empty values to `notspecified` should i do something like 

coalesce(col1,notspecified) col1

Comment: Basically, yes. Just don't forget to surround you string with single quotes though (`'not specified'`)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Athena, I can assume you have read only access and cannot really update the original data.

In your case, if you'd like to represent the nulls as 0 you can use `IFNULL(column, 0)

For more information about IFNULL you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

Comment: I think Athena is not supporting IFNULL